# Cosa significa "colui"?

Tags: word-choice, translation, difference, pronouns

Sto leggendo un libro, e ho incontrato una parola: "colui".  Ho cercato questa parola nel mio dizionario, ma è scritto che "colui" = "he". E allora, quando devo usare "colui" e quando devo usare semplicemente "lui"?

Comment: Se il tuo italiano è sufficientemente buono, ti consiglio di cominciare a usare un dizionario monolingue (cioè solo italiano) per imparare parole nuove. In questo caso, per esempio: [colui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/colui/).

Comment: E, già che ci siamo, in italiano c'è un altro modo per dire *he*, che anzi in origine era il modo principale: “egli”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Colui: (pronome dimostrativo, formale)

> - forma rinforzata del pronome  di terza persona ***lui***, usata specialmente  nella forma relativa ***colui che***, equivalente a ***chi***.

Anche *colei e coloro*.

- Colui che pensa di essere senza peccato, alzi la mano.
- Chi pensa di essere senza peccato, alzi la mano.